# Read-only folder in File Explorer

Tags: windows-explorer

In File Explorer, when I set a file's attributes to Read-Only, it says "R".
But when do this to a folder, it just says "D", no difference.  Is this normal?  Can it be changed so that the attributes of the folder are shown?

Comment: This is not true of Windows 10, which correctly displays `RD`. At least, it does in the 1709 version.

Answer (score 4):

Windows is inconsistent in the setting and display of directory (folder) attributes. As shown below in Windows 10 v. 1803 (OS Build 17134.112):

- The *Read-only* attribute of a folder can be set using the command-line option `+r`.
- The *Read-only* attribute of a folder is displayed in the CMD prompt as `R` meaning *Read-only*.
- In Windows Explorer, `Attributes` are displayed as `RD`, meaning *Read-only* and *Directory*.
- Right-clicking on the folder and selecting *Properties* displays only the `Read-only` attributes of the folder's *contents*.
- Changing the `Read-only` attribute in the *Properties* dialog affects only the folder's *contents*.

[image: Folder attributes]

That said, marking the folder `Read-only` has little utility in Windows. Any files created in the folder have their own attributes rather than that of the parent folder. By changing the `Read-only` attribute of a folder in the *Properties* dialog, though, you can choose to make all contained files `Read-only`.

Also note that Windows seems to blithely ignore the `Read-only` attribute of a folder, in that any attempt to insert, delete or modify files in that folder is processed without warning.

Comment: That's [documented](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/file-attribute-constants) and so presumably(?) by design.